# How to set value of form input field?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, qweb, odoo-12

This is my form input field (without classes and such):

```
<input id="input_partnerID" type="value" name="partner_id" value=""/>
```

I want to set the input value to the contact id of the logged in user. I can get that value with this Qweb code:

```
<p id="value_parterID" t-esc="user_id.partner_id.id"/>
```

And to get that value in my input form I use this javascript. The method is called when the "accept terms and conditions" button is clicked.

```
     function getID() {
        document.getElementById("input_partnerID").value = document.getElementById("value_parterID").innerHTML;
     }
```

This works but probably isn't the most efficient way to do this.

How can I use Qweb to fill in the input value in 1 or 2 lines preferably without javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the attribute value using `t-att-value=""`.

So in my case I should use this input field:

```
<input type="value" name="partner_id" t-att-value="user_id.partner_id.id"/>
```

Which does the same as the given example with the <p> and javascript.